# Background video responsive

Tags: html, css, video, background, responsive

Is there a way to make a video responsive?
On a mobile phone, the video is too big. I tried giving it `width : 100%` and `height: auto`, but then there were white bars.

[Website](http://ondrej.sabrnak.cz/)

Answer (score 0):

It will auto adjust the height based on the width.

HTML

```
<div class="flex-video">
  <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V9gkYw35Vws" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-video {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-video iframe, .flex-video video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Code copied from http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-video.html

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use jQuery library for background video. It will work perfectly. Here is the example:

http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/example-ambient.html